# XML alternative of Text.JSON.Generic for Haskell

Tags: xml, generics, haskell, xml-serialization, serialization

Is there any XML-(de)serializer for Haskell using `Data`/`Typeable` with functions similar to

```
toXml :: Data d => d -> XmlValue
fromXml :: Data d => String -> Result d
```

in the spirit of Text.JSON.Generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [TypLAB article](http://blog.typlab.com/2009/11/writing-a-generic-xml-pickler/)—it uses generic programming ([multirec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multirec) rather than [SYB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb)) to convert from and to XML.

Comment: I would prefere to use Data & Typeable since I want (1) one set of type classes to (de)serialize xml/json/... and (2) want to be able to derive the type classes automagically.

Comment: @finnsson almost everything can still be derived automatically. Instead of one line "deriving (Data, Typeable)" for SYB, you'll have to write 4 lines for multirec (See the last code block in the typLAB article). Slightly more verbose, but still manageable I'd say.

Comment: @Tom do you know if there's any json-lib using multirec?

Comment: Hi finnsson, just to make sure, it's no problem if you use several generic programming libraries. You don't need to do any generic programming to use generic functions. So I'd say: go for SYB JSON and MultiRec XML.

Comment: I'll go with the SYB/MultiRec-solution for now and see if I can either write a MultiRec-solution for JSON or a SYB-solution for XML later on.